# Using an RDP file as an Application under Azure RemoteApp

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, rds, remoteapp

I have implement Azure RemoteApp under a hybrid deployment and all the applications installed on the VM are being published.

But there are some applications that are hosted on other servers and we want it to be published and controlled via Azure RemoteApp.

Is there a way we can publish external applications on Azure RemoteApp that are hosted on a different server?

Answer (score 1):

Simply publish `mstsc.exe` as an application and add the /edit parameter to provide a `.rdp` file.